# Is there a way to append a folder to the PATH environment variable in vimrc?

Tags: vim

I'm running portable python and portable gvim.  When I run gVimPortable, I want it to append python to the PATH environment variable.  This is the command I would run in a command prompt:

```
path=%path%;C:\portable\PortablePython_1.1_py2.5.4
```

Is there a way to automate this in the vimrc file or some other way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change environment variables inside Vim using the [:let](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:let-environment) command.

```
let s:portablepy = 'C:\portable\PortablePython_1.1_py2.5.4'
" Add PortablePython's path to $PATH if running on Windows and PortablePython exists
if (has('win32') || has('win64')) && isdirectory(s:portablepy)
    let $PATH .= ';' . s:portablepy
endif
```